# Redis ServiceStack Native Client Instantiation Specifying connection settings

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I'm having some issues with the ServiceStack Redis client.
Right now, I'm able to create a client specifying the hostname and the port, but what about passwords or multiple servers. Im doing it like this:

```
protected IRedisNativeClient GetRedisClient()
    {
        if (_RedisHostName == null)
        {
            _RedisHostName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get(REDIS_HOST_SETTING_KEY);
            _RedisPort = Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get(REDIS_PORT_SETTING_KEY));
        }
        return RedisClientFactory.Instance.CreateRedisClient(_RedisHostName, _RedisPort);
    }
```

I have seen examples where people use PooledRedisClientManager and passes a connection string but the overloads I have access don't accept a String (v2.2.0.20691). For example:

```
    public PooledRedisClientManager();
    public PooledRedisClientManager(params string[] readWriteHosts);
    public PooledRedisClientManager(IEnumerable<string> readWriteHosts, IEnumerable<string> readOnlyHosts);
    public PooledRedisClientManager(IEnumerable<string> readWriteHosts, IEnumerable<string> readOnlyHosts, int initalDb);
    public PooledRedisClientManager(IEnumerable<string> readWriteHosts, IEnumerable<string> readOnlyHosts, RedisClientManagerConfig config);
    public PooledRedisClientManager(IEnumerable<string> readWriteHosts, IEnumerable<string> readOnlyHosts, RedisClientManagerConfig config, int initalDb);
```

Basically my questions are:

- What's the best way to get IRedisNativeClient instances?
- Is that GetRedisClient method ok? Im calling it every time I need to make a Redis operation

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have seen examples where people use PooledRedisClientManager and
>   passes a connection string but the overloads I have access don't
>   accept a String (v2.2.0.20691).

This Constructor does accept a string:

```
public PooledRedisClientManager(params string[] readWriteHosts);
```

Where you can create a new instance with a [Redis Connection String](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#redis-connection-strings), e.g:

```
var connStr = "redis://clientId:pass@host:1?ssl=true&db=0&connectTimeout=2&sendtimeout=3";
var redisManager = new PooledRedisClientManager(connStr);
```

You can call `GetClient()` whenever you want to access the client and dispose of it back into the pool whenever you're finished with it, e.g:

```
using (IRedisClient client = redisManager.GetClient())
{
   //..       
}
```

The `GetClient()` API returns an `IRedisClient` which is always an instance of the  `RedisClient` concrete type which inherits from `RedisNativeClient` so the single instance can safely be cast freely between any of the types below:

- RedisClient
- IRedisClient
- RedisNativeClient
- IRedisNativeClient